# What is Emacs Key Theme?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, themes, 17.04, emacs

I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and in Gnome Tweak Tool I have a menu called **Keyboard and Mouse**. In there I see **Key Theme** and I can select between **Default** and **Emacs**, but I haven't installed that. From reading a bit online I think it has something to do with typing, but what exactly?

**What is it used for?**

**Do I need it?**

**Can I remove it?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't use that but from reading I believe it makes your keys behave like the famous text editor `emacs` so changing it will mean you want to use your keys like you would on `emacs` text editor. As for removing it, I don't feel it's necessary to do that.

I [article post](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/gtk3-emacs-key-theme.html) will help you a bit on what it's for.